# dividing user entered data in javascript

Tags: javascript

here are the instructions I was given:

Include 2 textboxes for user to enter 2 numbers. Advise user to enter 0 in
the second textbox so you can display the results of division by 0. Advise
user to enter a string to see the result. The first operation is to see the
result of division by 0. The second operation is to see the result of using a
text string in a mathematical operation. Button – call the function and
display the result

my html:

```
        <form>
            Enter a number: <input type="number" id="number_box_1">
            Enter a number: <input type="text" id="number_box_2">
            <input type="button" value="Does Something" id="does_something" onclick="Division()">
            <input type="reset">
            results: <input type="text" id="math_results">
        </form>
```

my javascript:

```
function Division(){
    var number_1 = document.getElementById("number_box_1").value;
    var number_2 = document.getElementById("number_box_2").value;
    // textbox where results will be shown
    var results_shown = document.getElementById("math_results").value; 

    results_shown = number_1/number_2;
}
```

I have tried several things but havent gotten it to work. I think I may need to use parseint() but even after some reading, I still not sure how to write it into my function, or if that would be the correct thing to use. I fell like theres something i should be using but unsure. what should I be using to be able to divide number_box_1 by number_box_2?

Comment: "but havent gotten it to work" --- what does it mean exactly? Does it output "I DO NOT WORK" on your screen?

Comment: @zerkms it means my code does not function correctly, that it does not display any results

Comment: If it does not display any results it means it does not function *correctly*.

Comment: @zerkms While I agree that "but haven't gotten it to work" is ambiguous, your suggestion of "it does not function correctly" is just as ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were storing the value of the result input instead of a reference to it, so you were just modifying a variable and not the actual value.

```js
function Division(){
    var number_1 = document.getElementById("number_box_1").value;
    var number_2 = document.getElementById("number_box_2").value;
    // textbox where results will be shown
    var result = document.getElementById("math_results"); 

    result.value = number_1/number_2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter a number: <input type="number" id="number_box_1">
  Enter a number: <input type="text" id="number_box_2">
  <input type="button" value="Does Something" id="does_something" onclick="Division()">
  <input type="reset">
  results: <input type="text" id="math_results">
</form>
```

However, I would do something like this.

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById("number_box_1");
var box2 = document.getElementById("number_box_2");
var result = document.getElementById("math_results");
var form = document.getElementById("form");

form.onsubmit = function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // To disallow the form's submission
    result.value = box1.value/box2.value;
}
```

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label>Enter a number: <input type="number" id="number_box_1" required></label>
  <label>Enter a number: <input type="text" id="number_box_2" required></label>
  <label>results: <input type="text" id="math_results" readonly></label>
  <div><input type="reset"> <input type="submit" value="Evaluate"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: I'll work on understanding your suggestion of how you would do this. Thats above my knowledge using the form.onsubmit.... portion. Thanks!

Comment: I just assigned an id to the form, then selected the form, then added a listener function for the submit event of the form, that is pretty basic. Just notice that in the example that doesn't do use that method, if you press enter while focused within the form, it will submit and unless you capture the submit event and prevent the default action, it will submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var results_shown = document.getElementById("math_results").value; 
results_shown = number_1/number_2;
```

You have to use:

```
document.getElementById("math_results").value = number_1/number_2;
```

Runnable example:

```js
function Division(){
    var number_1 = document.getElementById("number_box_1").value;
    var number_2 = document.getElementById("number_box_2").value;
    // textbox where results will be shown
    document.getElementById("math_results").value = number_1/number_2; 
}
```

```html
<form>
            Enter a number: <input type="number" id="number_box_1">
            Enter a number: <input type="text" id="number_box_2">
            <input type="button" value="Does Something" id="does_something" onclick="Division()">
            <input type="reset">
            results: <input type="text" id="math_results">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the result into the `.value` property. Right now you are assigning it to the `results_shown` variable.

Also, you have to be careful with forms, or it might cause a page post which would appear to knock out the results.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the errors like division by 0 or division by string based on the responses coming you have to manually check what is the `results_shown` and then output to the result input box.

But I guess this is the start point.

```js
function Division(){
    var number_1 = document.getElementById("number_box_1").value;
    var number_2 = document.getElementById("number_box_2").value;
    // textbox where results will be shown
    var results_shown;
    try{
      results_shown = parseInt(number_1)/parseInt(number_2);
    }catch(e){
      results_shown = e;
    }
    document.getElementById("math_results").value = results_shown; 
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter a number: <input type="number" id="number_box_1">
  Enter a number: <input type="text" id="number_box_2">
  <input type="button" value="Does Something" id="does_something" onclick="Division()">
  <input type="reset">
  results: <input type="text" id="math_results">
</form>
```